# How to prevent indirect feature dependencies with cargo?

Tags: rust, dependencies, rust-cargo

When compiling a Rust workspace composed of multiple packages, is there a way to make `cargo` error when the succesfull compilation of a package `foo` depends on features that are *not* enabled by `foo` nor its dependencies?

Let me give a concrete example. With the workspace described below `cargo build` succeeds, but `cargo build -p foo` gives a compilation error because a `tokio` feature is missing in `foo/Cargo.toml`:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `tokio::io::AsyncWriteExt`
 --> foo/src/lib.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use tokio::io::AsyncWriteExt;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^-------------
  |     |          |
  |     |          help: a similar name exists in the module: `AsyncWrite`
  |     no `AsyncWriteExt` in `io`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `foo` due to previous error
```

This is bad! `cargo build` happily accepts usages of [indirect dependencies](https://jlbp.dev/JLBP-22). That is, changing code that is *not* in `foo` nor in its dependencies (i.e. removing the `io-util` feature from `bar/Cargo.toml`) can introduce compilation errors in `foo`. I would like to detect and prevent this without having to try each time to compile each single package individually.

---

Structure of the workspace:

```
.
├── foo
│   ├── src
│   │   └── lib.rs
│   └── Cargo.toml
├── bar
│   ├── src
│   │   └── main.rs
│   └── Cargo.toml
└── Cargo.toml
```

`./foo/src/lib.rs`:

```rust
use tokio::io::AsyncWriteExt;

pub fn dummy(_: impl AsyncWriteExt) {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

`./foo/Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[package]
name = "foo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
"tokio" = "1.21.2"
```

`./bar/src/main.rs`:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

`./bar/Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[package]
name = "bar"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
"tokio" = { version = "1.21.2", features = ["io-util"] }
"foo" = { path = "../foo" }
```

`./Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[workspace]
members = [
    "foo",
    "bar",
]
```

Comment: I think in general Cargo will *not* allow indirect dependencies, but in case of workspace, since you control all the members, it's not considered an indirect dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `cargo build --workspace` isn't sufficient for this, as it builds all package members at once, performing feature unification.

To build every package in a workspace individually, you can use the [`cargo-hack`](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-hack) subcommand.

To install the subcommand, run:

```
cargo install cargo-hack
```

Once it's installed, you can run the following command to build all workspace packages individually:

```
cargo hack build --workspace
```

The output is as you expect:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `tokio::io::AsyncWriteExt`
 --> foo/src/lib.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use tokio::io::AsyncWriteExt;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^-------------
  |     |          |
  |     |          help: a similar name exists in the module: `AsyncWrite`
  |     no `AsyncWriteExt` in `io`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `foo` due to previous error
```

This is the equivalent of building each package individually, but can be done in a single command. See the [README entry for the `--workspace` flag](https://github.com/taiki-e/cargo-hack#--features---no-default-features) for more details.